# Linked CSS and JavaScript files that include Session ID in URL give a 404

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I'm very new to .NET (I'm a front-end developer) but a client is having me set up their ASP.NET project on my computer. I've managed to get everything running, however one issue is that all the CSS and JavaScript files are returning a 404 error. The URL for these files includes the Session ID, like:

GET http://localhost/ProjectFolder/(S(q4szfkzkrkav0szfkzkr0))/css/style.css 404

The /css/style.css file definitely exists.

The pages use the Session ID in the URL and they load OK, like the login page:

http://localhost/ProjectFolder/(S(q4szfkzkrkav0szfkzkr0))/login.aspx

I'm using the exact same code as other people on the project and it works fine for them. Any ideas what could be wrong?

EDIT: Here is how the JS and CSS are being included. Keep in mind this is how the client's ASP devs set it up and apparently it works for them. Both of these files are returning 404s.

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/site.js" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: can you remove the session id in the stylesheet urls? I imagine that it will be changing so that static lookup that happens for stylesheets won't work

Comment: Can you post how the css page is added to the page? Example:`<link href="/FolderPath/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: @gotmilk13531 I've edited my post to include it.

Comment: @CoburnBerry it's automatically inserting the session id into the url.

Comment: Try `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">`

Comment: @gotmilk13531 Do you think it could be something else though? That may work, but I know some of the other devs are using sub folders, e.g. /Sites/Client/Project/.

Comment: Are you running this on your local IIS? It is possible you have something setup different here than the other devs. Your physical path may differ from theirs.

Comment: Yep, it's running on localhost. I know another one of the devs is using the same path as I am and it's working for him, he just doesn't know enough about IIS/VS/ASP.NET to help me with the problem. I suppose I could just use my own paths to the external files on my local setup and just do it again every time a file is updated. Not ideal though.

Comment: When they go to the login page, is their url the same as yours (aside from the session jibberish)?

Comment: Yep, he sent me a screenshot of some different screens and his URL is the same. Except, in the browser it's the same, but in the Visual Studio screenshot, in the Properties window when a folder is selected, his URL includes a port as well (4926). In the browser the port wasn't in the URL in the screenshot he sent.

Answer (score 0):

1)Does the folder name actually starts with "(" ,cause the 404 shows when actually nothing exists.
2)Check for the Session handler.
3)Where are you running your asp pages,if you are using visual studios then there might not be any problems cause it shows all the active connected pages including CSS.
4)Even that's not it...then there is a connection error in your html page

Comment: 1) The "(" part is the start of the session id. This site is using cookieless sessions 2) Not sure how to check that 3) I'm not "running" them from Visual Studio, they're being run through IIS.